# SQL Server Express: something better than LIKE for queries of SIMILAR names

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I need a special operator that's maybe a bit better than LIKE to query for "similar" values.

THE SCENARIO:
I have a table of students, and I have a table of lessons. The table of lessons was imported from other software, so the `StudentID` column is null on the imported rows. So we need the user to manually select the appropriate student row for each lesson, and then the `StudentID` column can be populated so they're properly synced. Both tables contain first and last names, but a lot of them are very likely to be misspelled.

After importing the rows, I would like to present the user with the names from the student rows where the names are "top five most similar" to the values stored in each lesson row.  In fact I'd like to present them in descending order from most-to-least similar.

A query containing the LIKE operator doesn't quite cut it because it requires specific text must exist within the column, and it doesn't return a "similarity score".

It is my understanding (from non-technical articles) that the US Post Office has this issue very well handled... People misspell names and street names all the time, but their algorithm for "find similar" is very effective.

I know the algorithm could vary from one solution to the next. For example I read from the article that some algorithms consider phonetics, others consider the count of vowels and consonants, while others consider that "T" sounds like "P" when spoken over the phone.

I COULD load every record into my app code and write my own algorithm in c#, VB.NET or whatever, but there are lots of problems with that including performance. I'd rather accomplish this within the query so I'm looking for alternatives.

I'm using SQL Server Express but I'm sure the solution applies to other database platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server supports the SOUNDEX() function, but this works only for similar sounding names and that not to well, at least if you handle non english texts. You could write you own function in c# or vb.net, facilitating any algorithm that might apply to your needs, and import it as a scalar function into sql server.

Comment: "You could write you own function in c# or vb.net, facilitating any algorithm that might apply to your needs, and import it as a scalar function into sql server."  I CAN?  Awesome!  If I understand correctly, I could write a "MYSOUNDEX()" function in vb.net and store it on the server and use it just like any other SQL function?  I have no clue how to do that, does this apply to SQL Express?  If I'm understanding you right, can you point me to any links with instructions to do so?

Comment: Looks like that's my answer.  Thank you very much!  And by the way this little tidbit can be handy in SO many ways!  It's the best thing since sliced stored procedures!

Answer (score 1):

SQL FreeText might work for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx

It searches against a Thesaurus, although i'm not sure how well it does with names.
Its very easy to implement, however.